# Fetching data with different static values

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following problem in my current application.
(The class examples should be understood as Entity Framework Entity classes.)

Lets assume you have a static class holding some properties, that are used application wide as an example in variaous Get/Set of properties.

The Get of the property is called everytime you request this property, with databinding to some control this propably happens everytime there is a redraw (layout refresh) of the control.

Now I am facing the problem that there can be the situation, that I desire to have 2 windows open with different "static" values, whats the best way to achieve this scenario?

Here some code that maybe makes things easier to understand:

The static class, holding properties that are used in queries:

```
public static class Core
{
    public string IdLang { get; set; }
    public string IdCompany { get; set; }
}
```

A class that uses the Core.IdLang in the get/set of the property Name:

```
public class Car
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            _name = (from x in LanguageTables
                    where x.IdLang == Core.IdLang
                    select x.Text).FirstOrDefault();

            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == _name)
                return;

            var languageTable = (from x in LanguageTables
                                where x.IdLang == Core.IdLang
                                select x).FirstOrDefault();

            if (languageTable == null)
            {
                languageTable = new LanguageTable();
                languageTable.IdLang = Core.IdLang;
            }

            languageTable.Text = _name;
        }
    }
}
```

Now lets assume you have 2 DataGrids in 2 different windows and want to bind a list of cars with two different languages.

I am doing the following (example only for 1 Grid and Window):

```
public class Window1 : Window
{
    List<Car> Cars;
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponents();
        Core.IdLang = "DE";

        Cars = new List<Car>();            

        //fetch data from Database, and populate the List<Car>

        Grid1.ItemsSource = from x in Cars
                            select x;
    }
}
```

Now just think about copy and pasting this above code (Window1) and have a second window and want to display all cars with their english names, so I changed the following code:

```
Core.IdLang = "DE";
```

To

```
Core.IdLang = "EN";
```

And thought everything would work out, but what ever Window you call later the Core.IdLang has now this value and once the Get/Set is called on either Window you would only receive or change it in this language and not differently between the windows.

In the real life application the Core class would consist of about 6 (or more) properties that are used in over 50 classes which all have minimum one property that has the same get/set code as you can see it the Car.Name sample.

Any of these classes could be used in the provided scenario where I would like to display english and german data next to each other for comparison.

Comment: If they change for each instance that uses it, `Core` shouldn't be a static class, rather a class that has properties that have default values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on you wanting to have different values I would ask: "Why are you forcing a static class in the first place?".  Most of the time when dealing with Entity Framework you can get a T4 generator to make the POCO (Plain Old Class Objects) for you and you relate to them.  However if you want to make a secondary level of explicit holding of properties for different languages why not just keep your 'Car' object as it is defined on the top but remove the Core Linq statements?

I am not getting from the example what that is acheiving for you except when a user puts in the wrong value.  You could always add a validation method seperately if it is must due to database foreign key constraints.  But why not limit a set a user can choose with a combobox or other for their choices first?  Then you have a blueprint you can keep for reuse for different circumstances or even put it in a constructor.  My example below is pretty explicit but you could take my logic and put it in other event methods.  I try to keep properties get and sets pretty basic and do the validation in other portions.  That way they IMHO are more well typed and there is less confusion with the pass in with what they will be.  EG:

EDIT 8-11-13 to be more specific

```
// I am the generated POCO form the Entity Model
public class Car
{
    public string IdLang { get; set; }
    public string IdCompany { get; set; }
}

// I am a class for just 'get' methods or update methods potentially
public class GetData
{
     // I am returning a single Entity of 'Car' type based on predicate
     public Car returnSpecificCar(string aLanguage)
    {
        using (EntityName e = new EntityName())
        {
            // I like lambda methods better due to less lines
            return e.Car.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Language == aLanguage);

            // Similar method in Linq style
            // return (from c in e.Car where c.Language == aLanguage
            // select c).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }

    // I return all cars
    public List<Car> returnAllCars()
    {
        using (EntityName e = new EntityName())
        {
            return e.Car.ToList();
        }
    }
}

// Simple console example
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] arts)
    {
        GetData d = new GetData();

        var cars = d.returnEntites();
        var specCar1 = d.returnSpecificCar("EN");
        var specCar2 = d.returnSpecificCar("DE");

        string ln = "-----All cars----" + Environment.NewLine;

        cars.ForEach(c => ln += c.CarId + "\t" + c.CarName + Environment.NewLine);

        ln += Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "----Specific Car1 -----" + Environment.NewLine;

        ln += specCar1.CarID + "\t" + specCar1.CarName+ Environment.NewLine;

        ln += Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "----Specific Car2 -----" + Environment.NewLine;

        ln += specCar2.CarID + "\t" + specCar2.CarName + Environment.NewLine;

        Console.WriteLine(ln);

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Now the key in my example is that I chose to give all cars or a specific car.  You could easily change the return to be List and return a list of cars where the language is a one to many relationship and then just filter through it.  I just wanted to show you could return a single object at a time DIFFERENTLY with a non static class.  Generally unless you need a repository of a certain conditioned class that is different than your database to track things outside of your database and only for the application, there is no need to make more POCO's up.  If they exist for a viewing platform for a UI like a ViewModel following an MVVM pattern maybe.  But for just populating a grid with exactly what is in the database there is no need to create a new class IMHO.  You just need return methods kept in a class that can be called on command that change on command.

With the example above if you want to apply to a grid I believe off the top of my head you may just do

```
GetData d = new GetData();

var items = d.returnEntities();

// Assumes your grid itemname is 'grid'
grid.ItemsSource = items;
```

Comment: As you may know, the Entity Framework always creates instances of the entities threw the empty constructor. So let assume you call the follow LINQ query. from car in Entities.Cars select car. Cars beeing the DbSet<Car> given from Entity Framework, how would I write the code or tell Entity Framework fill the DbSet<Car> with my constructor and my given parameters?

Comment: The entity is just a container object class.  Replace List<Car> with List<(entitycreatedPOCO)>.  Generally with Entity Version 5 it makes it very simple.  You just need to follow the properties.  So if Car was a table it would have two columns.  To populate you would just declare '(EntityPOCO) container = New (EntityPOCO) { (Column1) = (value you put in), (Column2) = (next value you put in) }'.

Comment: But again you are creating new Cars with only the values specified, I desire to fetch data from database (like the Entity Framework does) and just extend the created classes with custom properties. So how fetch from database, and in the same time initialize my cars with a custom constructor?

Comment: I don't get why are creating another class to just populate with what you should already have from Entity Framework's model creation.  You could have a custom get method to just return List<Car> with the language you want like:  private List<Car> returnCars(string aLanguage)
        {
            using (EntitiesName e = new EntitiesName())
            {
                return e.Cars.Where(n => n.Language == aLanguage).ToList();
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

This is very brittle code because you have external dependencies on `Core` within your `Car` class.  If you want all your classes to have `IdLang` automatically then you should use inheritance to achieve it.  Otherwise you could use `Dependency Injection` and just pass `Core` as a parameter through the `Car` constructor.

Personally, I see no use in having the `Core` class at all.  You can drop those two Properties IdLang and Company into `Car` and initialize them through the constructor.